# How to keep ConnectionString after Dispose in DbConnection?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have some code as below:

```
public class MyDatabase
{
    private DbConnection _myConnection;
    public MyDatabase(DbConnection connection)
    {
        _myConnection = connection;
    }
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        using (DbConnection connection = _myConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

    }

}
public class Context
{
    public void Run()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "...";

        MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(sqlConnection);
        db.RunMethod();
        db.RunMethod();
    }
}
```

When `db.RunMethod` call first time. It's okay. But when the method call the second time, it will throw `Exception`.

I know exactly why this is so. It's because the `_myConnection` is `Disposed` when it called in the first time.
I don't want to create new instance of `DbConnection` every call the `RunMethod` like this:

```
using(DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
```

Because, It's may be `SqlConnection` or `OracleConnection` or something else.

Should I remove `using` or have a better solution?

Comment: Just create a new instance and be done with it. Dont cache db connections, they are already pooled and cached internally

Comment: As I said above. I want to create a single times for my connection

Comment: like @TheGeneral said. connection object is not sth you pass around. create it in the block you're using it and do away with it. there is no performance issue with this.

Comment: you can remove using or you can create a new connection if it is already disposed.

Comment: @nimahabibollahi Is it have any problem if I remove `using`?

Comment: @mikenlanggio do you know about [Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)? That's the reason why it is a bad idea to keep a connection around. But if there other motives that push you to use a single connection you really should explain them.

Comment: @mikenlanggio yes,see it here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/5U7wnF   the code would be: DBConnection connection=_myconnection;

Answer (score 0):

If I am right about your design then you should move the responsability to create and destroy the connection to the `Context` class and let the `MyDatabase` class to be dependant on a connection alread setup to do its work and never handle its lifetime.

```
public class MyDatabase
{
    private DbConnection _myConnection;
    public MyDatabase(DbConnection connection)
    {
        _myConnection = connection;
    }
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log execption details 
        }
    }
}
public class Context
{
    public void Run()
    {
        using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
        {
             sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "...";
             sqlConnection.Open();
             MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(sqlConnection);
             db.RunMethod();
             db.RunMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

This will help you also when you need to have transactions around some methods that should run all to completition before committing anything to the database. In that case I would also suggest to remove the single try/catch in the RunMethod and move them to the Context class and log everything there.

Of course having a public MyDatabase class could require some of self-discipline in correctly handling the connection. Perhaps another good design change would be to make that MyDatabase class a private one and only usable through the Context class